# Logical Indexing of a Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrices:

```
Data = [1 NaN 2; NaN NaN 3 ; 1 NaN NaN]
Data1 = [8 3 2; 4 5 3 ; 9 6 7]
```

I would like to select only those values of Data1 such that the corresponding elements in Data are equal to 1.

My attempt with logical indexing returns me only a vector.

```
Want=Data;
Want(Want~=1)=NaN;
idx=Want==1;
Data1(idx)
```

But Data1(idx)=[8 9]. On the other hand, I would like to obtain:

```
Want = [8 NaN NaN; NaN NaN NaN; 9 NaN NaN]
```

Thank you.

Comment: `My attempt with logical indexing returns me only a vector.` Don't you think it would be useful to include your attempt with the question?

Comment: You are right. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with `Data1`, you make no mention of it in your question and it's completely unrelated to the desired operation on `Data`. `Want==1` is not going to return indices, [it's going to return a logical vector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html). You want [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

Comment: @excaza I have tried to explain myself better in the updated question. I know idx should return me a logical matrix. This is what I want.

Comment: No, logical indexing is not what you want. If `A = [1 2 3];`, then `A([false true false])` is going to return `2`, which is exactly the behavior you are seeing. Passing `false` as an index tells MATLAB you *do not* want that data. Again, you want `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to change all the elements different to 1 to NaN you can simply select all those elements using `Data~=1`, therefore you can simply assign the value NaN to those elements:

```
Data(Data~=1)=NaN
```

Comment: Maybe provide a little description to explain your logic to the OP so they can understand exactly what you're doing and apply the logic to future problems?

Comment: Alessandro, thank you so much for your help. Your solution does the trick. But I still need to apply logical indexing to a matrix because I want to keep the elements of another matrix Data1 only when Want==1. So I think I really need logical indexing in my case.

Comment: @user3618451 this *is* logical indexing

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear. Suppose I have idx=Want==1; and Data1=magic(3). I want to obtain M(idx), which is unfortunately a vector.

Comment: @user3618451 that's a *completely* different question. I suggest editing your post and asking the question you actually want the answer to. This answer provides exactly what you ask for in your question.